# How do I use the animation-iteration-count parameter to stop this animation from repeating?

Tags: css

Right now I'm using a really long fade out time to give the impression that the element is gone, but know there is a better (and simpler) way to do this.

I want the animation to complete, then leave the text completely faded out.

I attempted to use the animation-iteration-count property, but don't think I put it in the right place.

```css
.gZFNLC {
  animation: fadeOut 100s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 100s;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut 100s;
  -o-animation: fadeOut 100s;
  -ms-animation: fadeOut 100s;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  3% {opacity:1;}
  4% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  3% {opacity:1;}
  4% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  3% {opacity:1;}
  4% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  3% {opacity:1;}
  4% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity:1;}
  3% {opacity:1;}
  4% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="gZFNLC">Image</div>
```

Comment: But how exactly did you put it? Your code doesn't have it specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `animation-fill-mode` to stop at your end-state.
[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

```css
.gZFNLC {
  animation: fadeOut 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="gZFNLC">Image</div>
```

If you want to display it for a specific time before fading away, you can use `animation-delay`.